# With ASP.Net MVC3 unobtrusive validation, is it possible to activate real time validation before the form is submitted?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate

When using MVC3 unobtrusive validation, the user initially fills in the form without any validation occurring. After the form is submitted and validation errors occur, validation then occurs in real-time as the user types and moves between fields. Is it possible to have this real-time validation behaviour switched on before the form is submitted?

Answer (score 1):

You could call `$form.valid()` to validate the whole form on page load but then they get a validation summary at the top (assuming you've enabled it) along with validation messages next to each input.

How about validating each field as it is changed? You could attach to the change event like so: `$fields.change(function (event) { $(event.target).valid() });` which would run `valid()` on the field after it is changed. You can of course substitute another event for change to match more closely the function you need.

I don't know of an official way to mimic the post-submit-attempt validation exactly...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure both ClientValidationEnabled and UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnable are set to true in your web.config.

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

Comment: Thanks Peter. Yea, those are both true. The client validation is working, I just want it to validate in response to keyup and unfocus events as soon as the page loads, rather than after the first click of the submit button.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var isValid = $('#formId').validate().form();
```